# Flow.js Inferring Return Type from Node Module

Tags: javascript, types, frontend, flowtype, static-analysis

I am typing a node module using `declare module` using Flow.js with a union return type.

```
declare module 'mymodule' {
  declare export default {
    myFunction: () => string | { errors: [] },
  }
}
```

But then when I use it in my application

```
import myModule from 'mymodule'

const { errors } = myModule.myFunction()
```

Somehow Flow.js is saying that it should be a string, and that `errors` does not exist on that returned value from `myFunction()`. In other words, it is inferring that it is a string even though it could be an object with `errors`.

Is Flow.js digging into the node module logic? I didn't think it went that far.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 1):

Flow doesn't know if `myFunction` will return a string or an object--the type of a variable assigned to the result of `myFunction` is `string | { errors: [] }`. Therefore, Flow wants you to treat the result as both and will not allow you to use the variable as an object or string until you prove to Flow that it really is one of them ([Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAYlC8UAUBKBA+KBnYAnAlgHYDmUAPlAN5QS64D2uWAXFANoC6UAvgNwBQAEwgBjADYBDXNABuUqAFsQMAK6ERwfPUKsYAkdpxQAHgkXK1GrYVQCkx1jgIkUvKAHp3NOo373W1LQMTKycPK4eXkG++ABmyKCQ9PGm8GlQAORORMQZaP7YeDkRnlCE9N7B-HEJ4BDJJgjpGfQARgBWosB5yA5UlYws7FzcJV7lA7j8QA)).